# how to download images from multiple urls from a column in a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I want to downloads images frp, multiple URLs from a column in a csv file and store it in a folder in my computer

I tried this does not work and give me errors:

```
import urllib.request
import csv
import os

with open('booklogo.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    
    for row in reader:
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(row['link'])
        title_filename = f"{row['title']}{ext}".replace('/', '-')
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(row['link'], title_filename)
```

[csv sample](https://i.postimg.cc/s2bPx6V3/errorscreen.png)

[error screenshot](https://i.postimg.cc/s2bPx6V3/errorscreen.png)

Comment: Can you show the errors?

Comment: 'ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [13], in <cell line: 5>()
      9 name, ext = os.path.splitext(row['link'])
     10 title_filename = f"{row['title']}{ext}".replace('/', '-')
---> 11 urllib.request.urlretrieve(row['link'], title_filename)'

Comment: ValueError: unknown url type: ''

Comment: Does you link include `https://`?

Comment: @maciek97x thank you for your interaction, please note that I'm still in the intermediate level in python

Comment: @maciek97x yes, it's included

Comment: Can you please show what you exactly pass to `urllib.request.urlretrieve`?

Comment: @maciek97x I have two columns the first one has links the second one has title,  so I want to download images from first column called link and rename the files with the title from the second column

Comment: But can you print exactly some `row['link']` ?

Comment: @maciek97x here is an example of the link https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C560BAQEj1zLFctOm0g/company-logo_200_200/0/1519893117261?e=1667433600&v=beta&t=De0ZFkVdqoUDw5aX2hYYT82iuU0z3FPHeluujALRno8

Comment: `print(row['link'])` before `urllib.request(...)`

Comment: @PlainRavioli yes it's printing some row links as you said but with the following error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [14], in <cell line: 5>()
     10 title_filename = f"{row['title']}{ext}".replace('/', '-')
     11 print(row['link'])
---> 12 urllib.request.urlretrieve(row['link'], title_filename

Comment: also I have this error  :  

ValueError: unknown url type: ''

Comment: But do these links have https:// prefix?

Comment: @maciek97x yes my csv file they have https:// prefix

Comment: share some of that `csv` file

Comment: @PlainRavioli I have some blank rows maybe it's affecting the running of the code ?

Comment: Yes, blank rows may cause error.

Comment: @iamtrappedman already shared in the post

Comment: @maciek97x so how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Do not try to retrieve the page if the url is empty

Comment: @MehdiElazzouzi share that as text, bro you want me to type all that just to test for some error ?

Comment: @iamtrappedman here is the links and titles

link title
https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C560BAQEj1zLFctOm0g/company-logo_200_200/0/1519893117261?e=1667433600&v=beta&t=De0ZFkVdqoUDw5aX2hYYT82iuU0z3FPHeluujALRno8 & Other Stories
https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C560BAQFfUmDy1Rp4Rw/company-logo_200_200/0/1599472465424?e=1667433600&v=beta&t=xCTZkPfroRpMtt5CPBCKyZ4VETa2sjp89j8jAhTVH2g #HomeOffice
https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C4E0BAQEMxZpTzr5zkA/company-logo_200_200/0/1636043494025?e=1667433600&v=beta&t=VYDdj8zkoNlYCBg4Y-U4WhVr7NDttjPD5VbnvOql8sY 1-800-FLOWERS.COM, INC.

Comment: @iamtrappedman please before testing the code try to leave some rows blanks

Comment: @MehdiElazzouzi can you also share your complete error

Comment: ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [13], in <cell line: 5>()
      9 name, ext = os.path.splitext(row['link'])
     10 title_filename = f"{row['title']}{ext}".replace('/', '-')
---> 11 urllib.request.urlretrieve(row['link'], title_filename)

Comment: File ~\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py:239, in urlretrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
    222 """
    223 Retrieve a URL into a temporary location on disk.
    224 
   (...)
    235 data file as well as the resulting HTTPMessage object.
    236 """
    237 url_type, path = _splittype(url)
--> 239 with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
    240     headers = fp.info()
    242     # Just return the local path and the "headers" for file://
    243     # URLs. No sense in performing a copy unless requested.

Comment: File ~\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py:214, in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    212 else:
    213     opener = _opener
--> 214 return opener.open(url, data, timeout)

Comment: File ~\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py:501, in OpenerDirector.open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    498 def open(self, fullurl, data=None, timeout=socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT):
    499     # accept a URL or a Request object
    500     if isinstance(fullurl, str):
--> 501         req = Request(fullurl, data)
    502     else:
    503         req = fullurl

Comment: File ~\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py:320, in Request.__init__(self, url, data, headers, origin_req_host, unverifiable, method)
    317 def __init__(self, url, data=None, headers={},
    318              origin_req_host=None, unverifiable=False,
    319              method=None):
--> 320     self.full_url = url
    321     self.headers = {}
    322     self.unredirected_hdrs = {}

Comment: File ~\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py:346, in Request.full_url(self, url)
    344 self._full_url = unwrap(url)
    345 self._full_url, self.fragment = _splittag(self._full_url)
--> 346 self._parse()

Comment: File ~\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py:375, in Request._parse(self)
    373 self.type, rest = _splittype(self._full_url)
    374 if self.type is None:
--> 375     raise ValueError("unknown url type: %r" % self.full_url)
    376 self.host, self.selector = _splithost(rest)
    377 if self.host:

Comment: ValueError: unknown url type: ''

Comment: @iamtrappedman sorry for sharing it in a multiple comments you know the limitation of character

Comment: just share a screenshot. and you said some rows are empty ?

Comment: @iamtrappedman already shared in the post

Comment: Please don't post images of text (code, errors, csv), and please don't use comments to clarify. Code is unreadable in comments. [Edit] your question instead. See also [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
name, ext = os.path.splitext(row['link'])
```

this splits the URL and assigns the extension to `ext`. but the URLs ( atleast those in image ) does not have an extension so `ext` is empty.

try this

```
import urllib.request
import csv
import os

with open('booklogo.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
        if row["link"] != '' and row["title"] != '':
            name, ext = os.path.splitext(row['link'])
            if ext == '':
                ext = ".png"
            title_filename = f"{row['title']}{ext}".replace('/', '-')
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(row['link'], title_filename)
```

Comment: OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [21], in <cell line: 5>()
     10 name, ext = os.path.splitext(row['link'])
     11 title_filename = f"{row['title']}{ext}".replace('/', '-')
---> 12 urllib.request.urlretrieve(row['link'], title_filename)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py:249, in urlretrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
    247 # Handle temporary file setup.
    248 if filename:
--> 249     tfp = open(filename, 'wb')
    250 else:
    251     tfp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)

Comment: could you please share all the code, so I will be able to test it correctly

Comment: I dont know if that would be helpful. Can you please try once again. I have updated the code. If this does not work i will send you my code

Comment: Thanks bro, I have a problem of indentation could you please send the whole code

Comment: please send me your code

Comment: @MehdiElazzouzi I have added full code.

Comment: it's working, Thank you, but it's downloading just a few images, how can I can I specify the folder of extracting the images and how can make thsi code download all the images

Comment: I really appreciate your patience

Comment: ok I will do that

Comment: I could not ask another question until after one day

Comment: create a seperate question if you need detailed answer. for folder just add the directory path to title_filename in correct format. for all images just add the urls to csv. it should work if all the urls are similar to these @MehdiElazzouzi